# Differential form is closed if the integral over a curve is rational number.

Tags: differential-geometry

The following problem comes from do Carmo's book *Differential Forms and Applications*, Chapter 2, Exercise 4:

Let $\omega$ be a differentiable 1-from defined on an open subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that for each closed differential curve $C$ in $C$, $\int_C \omega$ is a rational number. Prove that $\omega$ is closed.

Can anyone give some hints? My idea was that we could try to show the integral vanishes if the curve lies in $N_\epsilon (p)$ (i.e. a small neighborhood around $p$) for any $p$ in $U$ and use the Poincare Lemma, but failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a closed curve is deformed continuously with a parameter, the integral varies continuously with the parameter as well.

Comment: Yeah, I and my friends also noticed that but how this can help?

Comment: How can a continuous function of a real variable take only rational values? (Hint: Intermediate value theorem.)

Comment: Got your idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can not make comment( Not allowed) so writing an answer.. I am not sure.. but please have it and tell me if you found mistake or confusion:

When take a continuous deformation of $C\subset U$, we will have continuous change in the integration:  Hence integral will be constant rational number in each connected component of $U$.

Now without loss of generality assume that $U$ is connected and integral is $0$.  Hence we have  $\int_C\omega = 0$ which gives that $\omega $ is exact, Hence closed.  This shows that $\omega $ is locally exact.   Hence closed...

Comment: Needs more careful argument I think. Anyway, Harald's hint is enough for us.